# Reinstall Apache?

Tags: homebrew, high-sierra, apache

I have completely borked my Apache installation on High Sierra.

I had a wonderful local development environment running prior to the update, and when I upgraded to High Sierra I attempted to force it to use PHP5 instead of PHP7 and in the course of doing so (and then trying to undo what I'd done) I made everything worse.

Regardless of what I do with apachectl commands, I just get:

*AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.*

I have Googled that many, many times and am only finding Linux / Unix sites with information that does not apply.

No, I can't find any useful information by looking at the results of tail logs.

No, I do not have / cannot use any of the ~previous or backup or "original" versions of httpd.conf or associated files (extras/httpd-vhosts.conf, etc.) because I have managed to corrupt them as well.

I also *may* have installed a second copy of Apache somewhere via Homebrew which is interfering with and / or causing the *de facto* High Sierra version to act wonky.

Is there any way -- without completely reinstalling the OS -- to reinstall *just* Apache and get things back to a stable state?

Comment: With the given details it's almost impossible to recommend anything else than: completely wipe the drive and reinstall macOS (or restore some working backup). We would need all httpd config files, a command history of all commands executed to repair the broken http server and the decisive/initial set-up guide for Apache & macOS (e.g. [Get Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin working on macOS Sierra](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/).

Comment: I tried editing my httpd.conf file and when that wasn't working, I followed the instructions here:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

My suspicion is that my problem is because of the line:
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null

Comment: And where are the previous (Sierra) instructions? The linked guide is focused on High Sierra and the changes necessary to run Apache & multiple PHP versions in a slightly different environment (brew) compared to Sierra (Apple).

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling the extra version of Apache I'd inadvertently installed with brew using:

*brew uninstall httpd*

Now when I *sudo apachectl -k restart* it runs the correct / *de facto* Mac OS version of Apache.